# What is the opposite of Peripheral?

Tags: antonyms

I want to know the opposite of the word peripheral.
For instance, one can have peripheral branches of the trigeminal nerve and upmost or something.

**What is the right opposite word of *peripheral*?**

Comment: A simple `central` comes to mind...

Comment: As others have said, 'central' is the most likely term in common English. However your example is from medicine which may very well have a technical term, like 'main' or 'primary' or 'proximal'.

Comment: Here, it might be [root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandibular_nerve). But this is really into specialist nomenclature.

Comment: Another specialist antonym would be `core` as in https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=core+periphery+model

Comment: One should note that in computer jargon a "peripheral" (noun) is a device that is attached to a computer.  Originally the term was used because the device would be external to the computer main box, on a cable, but  over time the term came to mean, eg, a tape or disk drive built into the main box.  I can't offhand think of a good antonym for this concept.

Comment: Ah, yes -- it came to me!  "Mainframe"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by the "opposite" of peripheral.

If you say that *peripheral* means *of the periphery, around the edges,* then one "opposite" is *at the centre,* or ***central***.

Comment: You are right here. I took only one example. I thought originally other thing than central as acronym. I thought about some general term.

Comment: I opened a new question here what I was looking for: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143560/what-is-the-correct-acronym-pair-for-upmost-and-deepest Thank you for this answer nevertheless!